# On the difference of truncated Gaussian and a new definition

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, truncation, truncated-normal-distribution

Given a r.v. $X \sim N(0, 1)$, what is the density of $Z = X I(\lvert x \rvert < \lambda)$. I am confused with the truncated Gaussian $Y = X$ if $\lvert X \rvert < \lambda$ otherwise $Y = 0$.

My question is that whether $Z$ and $Y$ has same density and why.

My attempt: I think the density of $Z$ is normal say $\phi(x)$ while the density of the truncated Gaussian $Y$ is $\dfrac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(\lambda) - \Phi(-\lambda)}$.

However one of my classmates argues that $Z$ and $Y$ have the same law.

Comment: $Z$ does not have a density, it has a probability atom at zero, otherwise, where it is non-zero, it is just a rescaled version

Comment: by the way, Wikipedia calls this a "rectified normal", not a "truncated normal".

Comment: everyone here is saying there's "no density", but of course they mean no density wrt the Lebesgue measure. The sum of the Lebesgue measure and a point mass at zero is a suitable dominating measure to establish and compare the densities you mention.

Comment: You describe a mixture of a truncated Normal distribution and an atom at zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z$ and $Y$ are identical since they are defined in the same way, but neither has a density because there is a nonzero probability of equalling $0$.

Explicitly, $P(Z=0)=P(Y=0)=P(|X| \ge \lambda) > 0$. You can similarly show that the CDF has a jump discontinuity at zero, and therefore cannot have a density.

The truncation of a random variable is usually *defined* to have CDF $F(t) = \frac{\Phi(t) - \Phi(-\lambda)}{\Phi(\lambda) - \Phi(-\lambda)}$ for $t \in (-\lambda, \lambda)$ and therefore density $\frac{\phi(t)}{\Phi(\lambda) - \Phi(-\lambda)}$. But I don't think you can express this truncated random variable as a function of $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: +1. But you *could* transform $X$ into a variable $\tilde X$ with the desired truncated distribution by applying the appropriate probability integral transforms ;-).  However, almost surely $X\ne \tilde X.$